# Does Entity Framework Core have an option to use a default value of 0 instead of null for non existent references?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If I have an object called Project that has a property called Creator and creator is a complex type, EF will automatically use the value null if the Creator property has not been assigned. Is it possible to instead use 0 instead of null in the database fields?

Answer (score 1):

No, that would break Foreign Key Constraints on the database side, since there wouldn't be a `Creator` row with a primary key of `0` for the `Project` row's foreign key to point to.

In a relational database, at least those that respect foreign key constraints, every relationship between rows is represented as a pair of primary, and foreign keys.  The database is designed to enforce that a foreign key *always* points to a valid primary key.  It will prevent you from updating a FK field to a value that doesn't exist in the PK field.  It will also yell at you for trying to delete the row that contains the PK as long as the FK still points to it (unless cascade-delete is turned on, but that gets complicated).

In theory, Entity Framework could probably be forced in to *trying* to do what you want, but the database would reject it, and EF would almost certainly have issues trying to retrieve rows with the 0/null value in it if it is configured to include navigation properties.

Comment: So, you've outlined that SQL, if configured with relationships, would have issues, of course. But what about EF? Is there a way to configure it to use 0 for empty-relationships as opposed to null?

Comment: EF needs a database to back it. There are no database that I know of that can use 0 instead of null to represent an "empty" foreign key.

Comment: Sure there is. SQL server.

Comment: You'll have to show me how that's done in SQL Server, because it isn't something I know how to do.

Comment: You make a column to represent your FK. You set it to int. You insert zeros into it.

Comment: Unless you actually apply the FK constraint, it won't actually be a FK. If it is a FK, 0 can't represent a null value because of referential integrity.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with calling it a FK (it is a key that references foreign data), without applying a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT. Semantics.